# Implementing variadic Max function in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates, function-templates

Despite, the fact, we have `std::max`, I wanted to try if it is possible to make a `Max` version that takes variadic arguments and calls the `Max`  recursively for finding the max element.

I saw similar posts in stack overflow, but those are old and most of them use `std::max` inside. Since I have a specific error and using a newer compiler, this post is not duplicated easily.

Following is the code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <format>
using namespace std::string_literals;

template <typename T>
constexpr T Max(T&& value)
{  
  return value;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr T Max(T&& value, Ts&&... args)
{
    const T maxRest = Max(args...);

    return (value > maxRest) ? value : maxRest;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::format("Maximum integer: {}\n", Max(1));
    std::cout << std::format("Maximum integer: {}\n", Max(5, 2, 10, 6, 8));
    std::cout << std::format("Maximum integer: {}\n", Max("string1", "string2"s));  // error in this line!!
    std::cout << std::format("Maximum double: {}\n", Max(3.14, 1.23, 2.56, 0.98));
    return 0;
}
```

For which I am getting:

```
main.cc(79, 21) : error C2440 : 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'const char (&)[8]'
main.cc(79, 21) : message: Reason: cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'const char [8]'
main.cc(79, 21) : message: No user - defined - conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
main.cc(87, 55) : message: see reference to function template instantiation 'T Max<const char(&)[8],std::string>(T,std::string &&)' being compiled
with
[
    T = const char(&)[8]
]
```

- I think the error is coming from the function call: `Max("string1", "string2"s));`. I do not know, how can resolve this.
- Likewise, I am also feeling that I am writing more to achieve this
  `Max` function in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20). Does anybody have any suggestion to
  make the two `Max` functions into one?

Comment: Do you really mean `Max("string1", "string2"s)` and not `Max("string1"s, "string2"s)`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes I wanted, `std::string`,`const char*` and `std::string_view`, and may be for all those have less that or greater than operator defined.

Comment: I see. You then need to deal with the case where only `const char*` are supplied.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Likewise, I am also feeling that I am writing more to achieve this `Max` function in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) [...] ?

Your `Max` function can maximize the simplicity by

- Having [abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template) (Since [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)) declaration, and
- The compile time branching with [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) (since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)).

```
constexpr auto Max(auto const& value, auto const&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 0u) // Single argument case!
        return value;
    else // For the Ts...
    {
        const auto max = Max(args...);
        return value > max ? value : max;
    }
}
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b4MaqYMb5)

**Update**: As pointed out in the comment section by *@TedLyngmo*, the above does not work if you only pass consecutive  `const char*`s (string literals). Ex. scenario

```
Max("string1"s, "string2", "string4", "string3") // result is "string2" instead of "string4"
```

Because this is resulting a pointer comparison rather than the comparison you want. It was the case also for your original shown code. You might want to handle this situation separately.

For instance, in the following code example, if the `value` is convertible to `std::string_view`, we convert it to `std::string_view` and do the greater check:

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_convertible

constexpr auto Max(auto const& value, auto const&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 0u) // Single argument case!
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<decltype(value), std::string_view>)
            return std::string_view{value};
        else
            return value;
    }
    else // For the Ts...
    {
        const auto max = Max(args...);
        return value > max ? value: max;
    }
}
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tes8e6xbd)

Likewise, each time when you use this `Max` function, always remember to check whether the passed argument is some type of pointer, which is clearly not handled by it.

---

> I think the error is coming from the function call: `Max("string1", "string2"s));` .
> I do not know, how can to resolve this.

When you call `Max("string1", "string2"s))`, the compiler deduces the `T` (i.e. return type), to be
`const char[8]`, that is the type of the first argument(i.e. `"string1"`). However, the second argument is a `std::string` (i.e. `"string2"s`). Now for the line :

```
const T maxRest = Max(args...);
```

this `std::string` must be now implicitly convertible to  `const char [8]`.This is not viable, and hence the compiler produces a type mismatch error.

To fix the issue, you can simply let the compiler deduce the type for you; That means, instead of defining or assuming the
the return type will be always `T`, use `auto` so that compiler can deduce the type for you.

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto Max(T const& value, Ts const&... args)
//        ^~~~ ---> Simply 'auto'
{
    const auto maxRest = Max(args...);
    //    ^~~~ ---> Simply 'auto'
    return (value > maxRest) ? value : maxRest;
}
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vqx9Whefd)

Alternatively, you could also use the [`std::common_type_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)
for defining the return type.

```
#include <type_traits> // std::common_type_t

        template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto Max(T const& value, Ts const&... args)
-> std::common_type_t<T, Ts...>
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: this is still comparing addresses of the string literals, no?

Comment: Wow that looks rather simple. Can you give me ref, where I can find  those features used?

Comment: oh right, I missed the `s` in `"string2"s`

Comment: In addition, you might use `std::less`/`std::greater` to handle unrelated pointer comparison.

Comment: I don't think `common_type` has a specialization for `string` and `const char*`.

Comment: It may need some special handling for `const char*`s. `Max("string1"s, "string2", "string4", "string3")` gives `string3` in gcc and `string2` in clang.

Comment: @JeJo It's those darn pointers :-) Perhaps catching `char*` and turning them into `string_view`s would be an option

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for bringing this up. I forgot that even `std::max`  had the same issue: [Why is std::max not working for string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127974/why-is-stdmax-not-working-for-string-literals/69128027#69128027). I have updated as per.. :)

Comment: @JeJo, You're right, I forgot and missed that it has the core ternary-based specialization that covers this case., almost like that's the entire point of `common_type` ;)

Comment: @JeJo: `"a" < "b"` is UB, whereas `std::less<>{}("a", "b")` is just implementation specific (compare pointer, not string content).

Comment: You have to use common_type to ensure all types are same. Creating `std::initializer_list<common>` seems the simpler, and get rid of variadic template for the remaining part.[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vorEbK63Y).

Comment: Up to OP to implement `Max(initializer_list<T>)` ;-)

Comment: Yeap. BTW The shown code also required to take care the case of string literals separately: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oY1cznodz

Answer (score 4):

> Likewise, I am also feeling that I am writing more to achieve this `Max` function in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)  [...]?

As extension to the other answer, using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), the `Max` can be made non-recursive as well.

```
#include <type_traits> // std::common_type, std::remove_cvref
#include <functional>  // std::greater

template<typename... T>  // common type helper
using CommonType = std::common_type_t<std::remove_cvref_t<T>...>;

constexpr auto Max(auto const& value, auto const&... args)
{
    CommonType<decltype(value), decltype(args)...> maxVal = value;

    return sizeof...(args) == 0u ? maxVal 
        : (((maxVal = std::greater{}(args, maxVal) ? args : maxVal), ...)
            , maxVal);
}
```

[Live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9EWfr3evo)

---

However, for the case of consecutive string literals, that requires some addition:

```
template<typename... T>  // common type helper
using CommonType = std::common_type_t<std::remove_cvref_t<T>...>;

// For string literals comparison.
constexpr auto handleStrLiterals(auto const& t)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<decltype(t), std::string_view>)
            return std::string_view{ t };
    else    return t;
};

constexpr auto Max(auto const& value, auto const&... args)
{
    CommonType<decltype(handleStrLiterals(value)), decltype(args)...>
        maxVal = handleStrLiterals(value);
    return sizeof...(args) == 0u ? maxVal 
        : (((maxVal = std::greater{}(args, maxVal) ? args : maxVal), ...)
            , maxVal);
}
```

[Live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rvqxM4f5P)